# OpenGL Simple Cube not Appearing, Using Uniform Blocks

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to draw a simple cube for a homework assignment for a class but for some reason it isn't showing up.

I am using uniform blocks and modern OpenGL. I am sure I am not doing something correctly.

My complete code is below. The below example depends on GLEW + GLFW + GLM.

What I found interesting is that for my light and material uniform blocks I get the index but the uniform block for my MVP matrix I don't get the index.

Any ideas?

Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#ifndef OPENGL_INCLUDES_
#define OPENGL_INCLUDES_

#include "GL\glew.h"

#ifndef GLFW_INCLUDES_
#define GLFW_INCLUDES_

#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <Windows.h>
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WGL
#elif defined(__linux__)
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xrandr.h>
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_X11
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_GLX
#endif

#include "GLFW\glfw3.h"
#include "GLFW\glfw3native.h"

#endif

#endif

#ifndef GLM_INCLUDES_
#define GLM_INCLUDES_

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/rotate_vector.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>

#endif

GLFWwindow* MainWindow;

#ifdef _WIN32

HWND MainWindowWin32Handle;

#endif

GLint WindowWidth = 1024;
GLint WindowHeight = 768;

GLulong SizeDivizor = 1;

GLboolean RiftAvailable = false;
GLboolean UseApplicationWindowFrame = false;

GLuint MainOpenGLShaderProgramID;
GLuint MatricesUniformBlockID;
GLuint MatricesUniformBufferID;

GLuint LightsUniformBlockID;
GLuint LightsUniformBufferID;

GLuint MaterialsUniformBlockID;
GLuint MaterialsUniformBufferID;

glm::mat4 ViewMatrix;
glm::mat4 ViewModelMatrix;
glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
glm::mat4 MVPMatrix;
glm::mat3 NormalMatrix;

class StandardCube;

std::vector<StandardCube> Cubes;

class StandardCube {

private:

    GLfloat* Vertices;
    GLfloat* Normals;
    GLuint* Indices;

    GLuint VAO;

    glm::mat4 ModelMatrix;

public:

    void LoadIntoOpenGL() {

        Vertices = new GLfloat[72]

        {
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f
        };

        Normals = new GLfloat[72] {
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
        };

        Indices = new GLuint[36] {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
            4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4,
            8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 8,
            12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 12,
            16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 16,
            20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 20
        };

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        GLuint MeshBufferID;
        glGenBuffers(1, &MeshBufferID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, MeshBufferID);

        GLuint TotalBufferData = (sizeof(GLfloat) * 72) + (sizeof(GLfloat) * 72);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TotalBufferData, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, sizeof(GLfloat) * 72, Vertices);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 72, sizeof(GLfloat) * 72, Normals);

        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 72));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        GLuint IndexBufferID;
        glGenBuffers(1, &IndexBufferID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBufferID);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLint) * 36, Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindVertexArray(NULL);

        ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    }

    void DrawMe() {

        MVPMatrix = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;
        ViewModelMatrix = ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;
        NormalMatrix = glm::transpose(glm::inverse(glm::mat3(MVPMatrix)));

        glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, MatricesUniformBufferID);

        glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, NULL, sizeof(glm::mat4), glm::value_ptr(MVPMatrix));
        glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::mat4), sizeof(glm::mat4), glm::value_ptr(ViewModelMatrix));
        glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::mat4) + sizeof(glm::mat4), sizeof(glm::mat3), glm::value_ptr(NormalMatrix));

        glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, NULL);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL, 1);
        glBindVertexArray(NULL);

    }

};

static void GLFWKeyCallback(GLFWwindow* p_Window, GLint p_Key, GLint p_Scancode, GLint p_Action, GLint p_Mods) {

    if (p_Key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && p_Action == GLFW_PRESS) {

        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(p_Window, GL_TRUE);
    }

    if (p_Key == GLFW_KEY_O && p_Action == GLFW_PRESS) {

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.1f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

    }

    if (p_Key == GLFW_KEY_I && p_Action == GLFW_PRESS) {

        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

    }

}

static void GLFWWindowResizeCallBack(GLFWwindow* p_Window, GLint width, GLint height) {

    //CurrentGLFWApplication->WindowResizeCallBack(p_Window, width, height);

}

static void GLFWMouseMovementCallBack(GLFWwindow* p_Window, GLdouble MouseX, GLdouble MouseY) {

    //CurrentGLFWApplication->MouseMovementCallBack(p_Window, MouseX, MouseY);

}

static void GLFWFramebufferSizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, GLint width, GLint height)
{

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

}

int initializeGLFWGLEW() {

    MainWindow = NULL;

    if (!glfwInit())
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "GLFW failed to initialize.");
        glfwTerminate();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE);

    if (UseApplicationWindowFrame) {

        MainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, "Basic Oculus Rift Example", NULL, NULL);

    }
    else {

        if (!RiftAvailable) {

            MainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, "Basic Oculus Rift Example", NULL, NULL);

        }
        else {

            GLint MonitorCount;
            GLFWmonitor** GLFW_Monitors = glfwGetMonitors(&MonitorCount);
            GLFWmonitor* MonitorToUse;

            switch (MonitorCount)
            {
            case 0:
                printf("No monitors found, exiting.\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("Two monitors expected, found only one, using primary...\n");
                MonitorToUse = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Two monitors found, using second monitor\n");
                MonitorToUse = GLFW_Monitors[1];
                break;
            default:
                printf("More than two monitors found, using second monitor\n");
                MonitorToUse = GLFW_Monitors[1];
            }

            MainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, "Basic Oculus Rift Example", MonitorToUse, NULL);

        }

    }

    if (!MainWindow)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not determine OpenGL version; exiting.");
        glfwTerminate();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(MainWindow);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();

    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

    glfwSetInputMode(MainWindow, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(MainWindow, GLFWKeyCallback);
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(MainWindow, GLFWWindowResizeCallBack);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(MainWindow, GLFWMouseMovementCallBack);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(MainWindow, GLFWFramebufferSizeCallback);

    glfwSwapBuffers(MainWindow);

    glfwPollEvents();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

int prepareOpenGL() {

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

int loadShaders() {

    // Create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Compile Vertex Shader
    printf("Compiling Vertext Shader.\n\n");
    char const * VertexSource = "#version 330 \n\n\
        layout(std140) uniform MatrixInformation {\n\
            mat4 m_pvm;\n\
            mat4 m_viewModel;\n\
            mat3 m_normal;\n\
        };\n\
        layout(std140) uniform Lights {\n\
            vec3 l_dir; \n\
        };\n\
        in vec4 position;\n\
        in vec3 normal;\n\
        \n\
        \n\
        out Data{\n\
            vec3 normal;\n\
            vec4 eye;\n\
        } DataOut;\n\
        \n\
        void main() {\n\
            \n\
            DataOut.normal = normalize(m_normal * normal);\n\
            DataOut.eye = -(m_viewModel * position);\n\
            \n\
            gl_Position = m_pvm * position;\n\
        }\n\
    \n";

    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check Vertex Shader

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);

    if (InfoLogLength > 0){

        std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength + 1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        std::string ErrorMessage = std::string(&VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    }

    printf("Compiling Fragment Shader.\n\n");
    char const * FragmentSource = "#version 330\n\
        layout(std140) uniform Materials {\n\
            vec4 diffuse;\n\
            vec4 ambient;\n\
            vec4 specular;\n\
            vec4 emissive;\n\
            float shininess;\n\
            int texCount;\n\
        };\
        \n\
        layout(std140) uniform Lights {\n\
            vec3 l_dir; \n\
        };\
        \n\
        in Data{\n\
            vec3 normal;\n\
            vec4 eye;\n\
        } DataIn;\n\
        \n\
        out vec4 colorOut;\
        \n\
        void main() {\n\
            \n\
            vec4 spec = vec4(0.0);\n\
            \n\
            vec3 n = normalize(DataIn.normal);\n\
            vec3 e = normalize(vec3(DataIn.eye));\n\
            \n\
            float intensity = max(dot(n, l_dir), 0.0);\n\
            \n\
            if (intensity > 0.0) {\n\
                vec3 h = normalize(l_dir + e);\n\
                \n\
                float intSpec = max(dot(h, n), 0.0);\n\
                spec = specular * pow(intSpec, shininess);\n\
            }\n\
        \n\
        colorOut = max(intensity *  diffuse + spec, ambient);\n\
    }";

    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0){

        std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength + 1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        std::string ErrorMessage = std::string(&FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    }

    // Link the program
    printf("Linking shader program.\n\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0){

        std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength + 1);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
        std::string ErrorMessage = std::string(&ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);

    }

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    MainOpenGLShaderProgramID = ProgramID;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

int prepareShaderUniforms() {

    glUseProgram(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID);

    LightsUniformBlockID = glGetUniformBlockIndex(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, "Lights");
    glUniformBlockBinding(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, LightsUniformBlockID, 2);
    glGenBuffers(1, &LightsUniformBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, LightsUniformBufferID);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 2, LightsUniformBufferID);

    GLfloat LightDirection[3] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(LightDirection), &LightDirection, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, NULL);

    MatricesUniformBlockID = glGetUniformBlockIndex(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, "MatrixInformation");
    glUniformBlockBinding(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, MatricesUniformBlockID, 1);
    glGenBuffers(1, &MatricesUniformBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, MatricesUniformBufferID);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, MatricesUniformBufferID);
    GLsizeiptr TotalBufferSize = sizeof(glm::mat4) + sizeof(glm::mat4);
    TotalBufferSize += sizeof(glm::mat3);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TotalBufferSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, NULL);

    MaterialsUniformBlockID = glGetUniformBlockIndex(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, "Materials");
    glUniformBlockBinding(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, MaterialsUniformBlockID, 3);
    glGenBuffers(1, &MaterialsUniformBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, MaterialsUniformBufferID);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 3, MaterialsUniformBufferID);

    GLfloat Material[18];

    //Diffuse
    Material[0] = 0.5f;
    Material[1] = 0.0f;
    Material[2] = 0.0f;
    Material[3] = 1.0f;

    //Ambient
    Material[4] = 0.2f;
    Material[5] = 0.2f;
    Material[6] = 0.2f;
    Material[7] = 1.0f;

    //Specular
    Material[8] = 0.0f;
    Material[9] = 0.0f;
    Material[10] = 0.0f;
    Material[11] = 1.0f;

    //Emissive
    Material[12] = 0.0f;
    Material[13] = 0.0f;
    Material[14] = 0.0f;
    Material[15] = 1.0f;

    //Shininess
    Material[16] = 2.0f;

    //Texture Count
    Material[17] = 0.0f;

    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(Material), &Material, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, NULL);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

int loadCubes() {

    StandardCube NewCube;

    NewCube.LoadIntoOpenGL();

    Cubes.push_back(NewCube);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

int prepareMatricies() {

    GLfloat AspectRatio = (GLfloat)(WindowWidth) / (GLfloat)(WindowHeight);

    ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, AspectRatio, 1.0f, 1000.0f);

    ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(4.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f),        // camera is at (4,3,3), in world space - Where the camera is inside world.
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),        // and looks at the origin - What point the camera is looking at inside world.
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)// head is up(set to 0,1,0) - the direction of up for camera.
        );

    glViewport(0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if (initializeGLFWGLEW() == EXIT_FAILURE) {

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    if (prepareOpenGL() == EXIT_FAILURE) {

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    if (loadShaders() == EXIT_FAILURE) {

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    if (prepareShaderUniforms() == EXIT_FAILURE) {

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    if (loadCubes() == EXIT_FAILURE) {

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    if (prepareMatricies() == EXIT_FAILURE) {

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(MainWindow))

    {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        for (auto & C : Cubes) {

            C.DrawMe();

        }

        glfwSwapBuffers(MainWindow);

        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 

layout(std140) uniform MatrixInformation {
    mat4 m_pvm;
    mat4 m_viewModel;
    mat3 m_normal;
};

layout(std140) uniform Lights {
    vec3 l_dir; 
};

in vec4 position;
in vec3 normal;

out Data{
    vec3 normal;
    vec4 eye;
} DataOut;

void main() {

    DataOut.normal = normalize(m_normal * normal);
    DataOut.eye = -(m_viewModel * position);

    gl_Position = m_pvm * position;
}
```

And here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 330
layout(std140) uniform Materials {

    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 specular;
    vec4 emissive;
    float shininess;
    int texCount;

};  

layout(std140) uniform Lights {
    vec3 l_dir; 
};  

in Data{
    vec3 normal;
    vec4 eye;
} DataIn;

out vec4 colorOut;

void main() {

    vec4 spec = vec4(0.0);

    vec3 n = normalize(DataIn.normal);
    vec3 e = normalize(vec3(DataIn.eye));

    float intensity = max(dot(n, l_dir), 0.0);

    if (intensity > 0.0) {
        vec3 h = normalize(l_dir + e);

        float intSpec = max(dot(h, n), 0.0);
        spec = specular * pow(intSpec, shininess);
    }

    colorOut = max(intensity *  diffuse + spec, ambient);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is this part:

```
//Binding uniform buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, MatricesUniformBufferID); 
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, MatricesUniformBufferID);
GLsizeiptr TotalBufferSize = sizeof(glm::mat4) + sizeof(glm::mat4);
TotalBufferSize += sizeof(glm::mat3);
//uploading to the unbound array buffer
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TotalBufferSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW); 
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, NULL);
```

So you need to change

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TotalBufferSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

to

```
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, TotalBufferSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Additionally uploading `NULL` doesn't work on my OpenGL driver (although it should), so I had to

```
std::array<unsigned char,sizeof(glm::mat4)*2+sizeof(glm::mat3)> buff;
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, TotalBufferSize, buff.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

As for how you would find that out: the old-school method is to litter your code with `glGetError` calls that only go off in debug mode. The more modern method is to create a debug context and print break on the callback to find out whereabouts the error is (then you can make `glGetError` calls in that area to get the exact function call if you don't know it by then, since modern OpenGL drivers are threaded and the callback may be triggered one or two function calls later).

Comment: Thank you for your assist! Unfortunately, I still don't see the cube. Edit** I wanted to paste updated code here but StackOverflow makes it so hard :(

Comment: So I wanted to paste the code here but I guess I will describe the change I made instead. I changed the enum(?) from `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` to `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER` as well as adding the "std::array" line exactly as how you wrote it above but I still don't see the cube. Did you see the cube after you compiled? Thank you.

Comment: @user3434662 well what if you setup a debug context, do you get any errors? I use this code: https://gist.github.com/Bigpet/ec9bddfedd075794c0d0 and it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/cOcLCxR.png

Comment: Thanks for the paste of the code and the result. Something with my system? I get an access violation with this line: `glDebugMessageCallback((GLDEBUGPROC)MyDebugCallbackARB, 0);`

Comment: Ahhh, I am using OpenGL 3.1. The debug callback is for [OpenGL 4+](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDebugMessageCallback.xhtml). Is the code I am working with only compatible with the more recent (2014+) OpenGL setups out there?

Comment: @user3434662 well you can load it as an ARB extension by just making it `glDebugMessageCallbackARB` and `GLDEBUGPROCARB`. Most OpenGL 3.1 implementations have the extension afaik

Comment: Thanks, still an access violation with this line: `glDebugMessageCallbackARB((GLDEBUGPROC)MyDebugCallbackARB, 0);` Also, to perhaps help troubleshoot the issue, this line isn't returning the actual Uniform Block Index for me: `MatricesUniformBlockID = glGetUniformBlockIndex(MainOpenGLShaderProgramID, "MatrixInformation");` Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @user3434662 you can try to load the function yourself: https://gist.github.com/Bigpet/ec9bddfedd075794c0d0/ca1c9b5ea5b358211d1aa07f785548a2eb1eeec5 or just delete the debug stuff and put a `glGetError` before and after the call that is problematic and print the values of both.

Comment: Hey, I figured it out; you need `layout (location=0)` and `layout (location=1)` in front of the position and normal incoming attributes.

Comment: I also marked your original response as the answer. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @user3434662 well location specifiers are also rather new. You can either set the location from outside the shader before linking or query the location after linking. But I also like explicitly specifying the location within the shader the most.